# Filter weekends on DatePicker angular material using moment.js

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, angular8

im trying to use Angular material DatePicker with moment.js
In my use case i need to exclude weekends.

On the material documentation they say how to do it with javascript default dates

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Datepicker with filter validation */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-filter-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerFilterExample {
  myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const day = d.getDay();
    // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

How can i achieve the same using moment.js?
i tried to find it on google, but just can't.

thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems you pasted the sample code from https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples
what about your code? how does moment come in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you are trying to do the same with a a datepicker that uses "moments" instead of dates as described [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) you are probably looking for `moment().weekday();`

try:

```
public myFilter = (d: any): boolean => {
    const day = d.weekday();
    // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
}
```

see the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/) documentation for more information

working example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ldpxoqraxoa